# Display error if the value is greater than 200

Tags: angular

I would like to display in `<mat-error>` what kind of error it is.

```js
primaryFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  hourlyRate: ['', [Validators.requiredTrue, Validators.max(200)]],
});
```

```html
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="this.primaryFormGroup">
  <label><input formControlName="hourlyRate" autocomplete="off" name="hourlyRate" id="wanted-hourly-rate" matInput placeholder="e.g., 50" type="number" appNumbersOnly></label>
  <mat-error *ngIf="hourlyRate.errors.maxLength">Typed number is greater than 200</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

As you see, I have tried it with `hourlyRate.errors.maxLength` but I get the error

> Cannot read property 'maxLength' of null

How can display an error if the typed number is greater than 200?

Comment: <mat-form-field [formGroup]="primaryFormGroup">, Check this

Comment: @GangadharGandi I have tried it with `*ngIf="primaryFormGroup.controls['hourlyRate'].hasError('maxLength')">` but the error won't display.

Comment: Does `<mat-error *ngIf="hourlyRate.errors?.maxLength">` eliminate the error?

Comment: @R.Richards no, the solution is what ender says. It's not `maxLength`, it should be `max`.

Comment: Ah, now that I look at your code again, yes that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a couple of problems:

1. `hourlyRate` is the name of a control in the `primaryFormGroup` property. It's not a property/template variable of the component so it cannot be referenced directly.
2. `max` and `maxLength` are two different validations. `max` validates a number value, while `maxLength` validates the number of input characters.

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8p5hwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8p5hwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that out but if type a number which is greater than 100, I will get an error. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-voddhn?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: In your stackblitz, the initial value of the control is set to `'300'`, which is causing the error. if you set it to something within your desired range or null, it will work

Comment: I have set it to `null` but I still get the error: Cannot read property 'max' of null

Comment: Looks like the error object wasn't updating for some reason, `.hasError` works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-voddhn?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Perfect, that's great. Thank you so much!